# Why would a 2 degree polynomial with 2 variables on intersecting with a line give either 0, 1 or 2 points?

Tags: geometry, elliptic-curves

For clarification, the 2nd degree polynomial with two variables is $f(x,y)$, and the intersecting line is also a (first degree) polynomial in $x$ and $y$.

> Why would the 2nd degree polynomial with 2 variables intersect with a line in either 0, 1 or 2 points?

I have no clue on how even to begin this, so any basic idea/hint would be helpful. I have tried a couple of straightforward easy examples, but I haven't been able to generalize it.

Comment: Start with a simple example, e.g. a circle.  Fix the equation of the circle and vary the equation of the line to get the various numbers of intersections.

Comment: Yes, I have tried a couple of straightforward easy examples, I haven't been able to generalize it though.

Comment: So let's be a little clearer about what you want to know.  Would it be enough to show that there cannot be more than two points of intersection?  Obviously there cannot be fewer than zero points of intersection.

Comment: Yes, that would be equivalent, i.e showing there can be at most 2 points of intersection, which is what I've been trying to do so too, but to no avail.

Comment: The intersection is a polynomial of degree 2 (in one variable). So, it has at most 2 roots.

Comment: well yes, i did think that would be the way to go, but would there be a better, say more formal way to approach it.

Comment: You can make that way completely formal.

Comment: Just a remark: by [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), there are $2 \cdot 1 = 2$ intersections (counted with multiplicity) in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$. One or both of these intersections could occur on the line at infinity (we could also have an intersection with multiplicity $2$), which lead to the possibilities of $0, 1$, or $2$ intersections in the affine plane.

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception to what the problem describes.  Let $f(x,y)$ be a second degree polynomial and $g(x,y)$ a first degree polynomial.   If $g$ divides $f$ as polynomials, then all (infinitely many) solutions to $g(x, y)= 0$ also solve $f(x,y)=0$.

Otherwise we can show that the equations $f( x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ have at most two solutions in common.  To begin note that since $g(x,y)$ is first degree,  at least one of the variables $x,y$ will have a nonzero coefficient.   Assume for the sake of argument that $y$ has a nonzero coefficient (otherwise we exchange the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the steps that follow).

Now rewrite the equation $g(x,y)=0$ as giving $y=mx+b$.

Substitute that for $y$ in the equation $f(x,y)=0$.  The result is an equation only in $x$ of degree (at most) two.

The point to be careful of is that because $g$ doesn't divide $f$, the result cannot simplify to $0=0$.  In other words there will not be more than two solutions for $x$ and corresponding solutions for $y=mx+b$.